# How to build to output folder when the typescript files are located in './src'

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

What I have:

```
./src/myfile.ts
./test/mytest.spec.ts
```

And **tsc** should create a javascript (`myfile.js`) and definition file (`myfile.d.ts`) in the `./build` location.

My tsconfig.ts:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "files": [
    "./src/index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    ".vscode",
    ".git",
    "build",
    "node_modules",
    "test"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

But this config file generates the `myfile.js` in the `./build/src/` sub-folder.

Note that I cannot use `"rootDir": "./src"` because then the test folder is not compiled (which gives problems when running tests with karma + webpack?)

Comment: I came across same issue and finally I ended up moving tests folder inside source and compiling files from root.

Comment: I would have a different tsConfig for your test files. Typically one does not deploy tests, so you likely don't want them to be in the same build folder as your production files...

Comment: You set root to . It should probably be ./src no? Because it thinks the /src/ folder needs to be transferred

Comment: @asperon indeed I meant ./src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And tsc should create a javascript (myfile.js) and definition file (myfile.d.ts) in the ./build location.

TypeScript is not nicely modeled to handle *bundling*. That is something you should use some other tool to do

## More

e.g. Webpack quickstart: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Don't recommend `out` / `outFile` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

Comment: Is it also possible to bundle multiple .d.ts files into one ?